# Is it because mutiple Numpy so as to failed building wheel for numpy on Mac OS Monterey ver 12 M1 Pro

Tags: python, macos, numpy

Could anyone comment whether multiple numpy installation is the reason for the error? If it is yes, what can I do?

Please let me explain the error here. When installing a package (argoverse https://github.com/argoai/argoverse-api ), I run into the following error on Mac while I didn't run into such problem while installing it on PC (x86). Error msg as shown below.

> ```
>         clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
>         error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10
> ```
>
> -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.c -o
> build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.o
> -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.o.d
> -faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers" failed with exit status 1
> [end of output]
>
> ```
>     note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
>     ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
>   Failed to build numpy
>   ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
>   [end of output]
>  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: subprocess-exited-with-error
> ```
>
> × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run
> successfully. │ exit code: 1 ╰─> See above for output.
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip.

After some research, I did

```
% brew doctor
```

and get the feedback like:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10-config
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3-config

Other info

> % python --version Python 3.8.9  % pip install numpy Requirement
> already satisfied: numpy in
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages
> (1.23.1)

And checking on python's version

> % python --version Python 3.8.9
> % python3 --version Python 3.10.4

Comment: Cannot really read through the lines but the different python versions can interfere badly with each other, unless you are using environments. Are you using eg. `venv` or `conda`?

Comment: @YannisP. nop. Does Conda work on Mac

Comment: both `venv`and `conda` do